# Is it possible to declare empty variable in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any explicit way in PHP to declare variable without assigning any value? Similarly to Java or Javascript? Something like this.

```
var $variable;
```

I assume that default value for this variable would be `NULL`. If it's not possible, is there any logical explanation why it wasn't implemented in PHP?

There are many articles with tables depicting boolean results of `isset`, `empty`, etc. And there is also an example of value `var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)`, but does it make sense to list it?

```
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|               Value of variable ($var)               | isset($var)  | empty($var) | is_null($var) |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| NULL                                                 | bool(false)  | bool(true)  | bool(true)    |
| var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value) | bool(false)  | bool(true)  | bool(true)    |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

https://www.virendrachandak.com/demos/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null.php

Comment: `var $var;` does not work outside of classes to begin with. (And inside, one should rather use the explicit visibility levels these days.)

Comment: You can use `$variable = null;`

Comment: Or even `$variable;`, but it is useless.

Comment: I didn't know about `$variable;`, however I expected this to be an expression that should throw `E_NOTICE` message if variable is not declared.

Comment: Just `$variable;` does literally nothing. It's neither trying to read the variable nor set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `var` keyword which works the same way as in javascript. From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp):

> Note: Unlike other programming languages, PHP has no command for declaring a variable. It is created the moment you first assign a value to it.

---

Your other question:

> If it's not possible, is there any logical explanation why it wasn't implemented in PHP?

One logical explanation could be that in PHP all variables start with a `$` symbol. So PHP immediately knows when something is a variable and not a function or keyword, without the need for a declaration.

In fact, javascript code also works without declarations, but here, they are still recommended in most cases.

---

If you want to declare a variable and set its value to `null` in PHP, just use:

```php
$myVar = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't have an explicit statement to initialise variables, like Javascript's `var`. PHP variables get initialised when they're first assigned to. It's a design choice, for better or worse. To create a variable you always have to assign something to it. Since a variable must have some value and PHP's value for "nothing" is `null`, you want:

```
$variable = null;
```

(Alternative ways to create variables exists, like references, e.g.: `parse_str($foo, $bar); var_dump($bar);`, but let's leave that aside.)

The `var` statement exists in Javascript to determine scope; Javascript has nested scopes and needs an explicit initialisation to determine what a variable's scope is. Scoping in PHP works differently and doesn't have that ambiguity, hence such a separate statement isn't necessary. Originally PHP also liked implicit globals a lot (a terrible idea in hindsight), which somewhat clashes with the idea of explicit initialisation statements in the first place.

> `var $var;` (a variable declared, but without a value)

That is an incomplete/incorrect quote, it should be *"a variable declared but without a value **in a class**"*, since that's the only place the `var` keyword can be used.

---

As an example, Python also uses initialisation-by-assignment, *and* also has nested scope. It uses a different approach to resolve this:

```
foo = 42

def bar():
    foo = 69

    def baz():
        nonlocal foo
        foo = 2
```

The rule in Python is, that a variable is local to a function if any assignment is done to the variable inside the function. So the `foo = 69` creates a new local variable inside `bar` here. To allow assignment to the variable from an inherited scope, the `nonlocal` or `global` keyword must be used to explicitly denote that variable as inherited. `foo = 2` here reassigns `foo = 69`, but neither reassigns `foo = 42`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how it works in javascript and python. However I don't understand why variables in classes don't need to be initialized.

Comment: Because they're not "variables" but *properties*, and PHP decided to go with a different mechanism there. Both Python and Javascript follow the same assignment-is-initialisation for properties as well, but PHP doesn't. That's PHP for ya… ‍♂️

Answer (score -1):

In class context you can make it without explicit `null`:

```php
class BarClass {
    private FooClass $foo;
```

As simple variable, you can't. Use `$variable = null` (or do not write it at all). As all not set vars are null by default:

```php
$var1 = null;

var_dump(isset($var1), empty($var1), is_null($var1));
// bool(false), bool(true), bool(true)

var_dump(isset($var2), empty($var2), is_null($var2));
// Notice:  Undefined variable: var2 - From `is_null`
// bool(false), bool(true), bool(true)
```